# "root/.bashrc about: command not found"

Tags: linux, shell

connect to remote machine from shell script using ssh command and do some operations.

Seeing **root/.bashrc about: command not found** error.

In check.sh file

```
ssh -i /root/pem/check.pem ec2-user@someaddress "grep commands"
```

*without the `grep` commands the about command in the remote machine is not putting up any errors*

`about` command in .bashrc is throwing error when trying to connect remotely. But the 'about' is working fine while i connect directly.

After connecting to this machine from ssh, any command is not working it seems.

Comment: There's so much that you left unmentioned...

Comment: You don't provide an identity file...

Comment: @Jahid please check see the edits.

Comment: What is the grep format, grep needs at least two arguement, `grep commands file`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ssh ec2-user@someaddress "grep commands"
```

`-i` asks for an identity file which you do not provide.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better provide the error output if you expect a satisfied answer from others.

Anyway, here is an example for you:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key -p SSHport ec2-use@someaddress "grep commands"
```

If you provide `-i` option, you should provide the SSH private key as well.

Since you put above command in a shell file named `check.sh`, here is what you can do :

```
chmod +x check.sh
./check.sh
```

Comment: **ssh -i /root/pemfiles/check.pem ec2-user@someaddress** is the command i am using and this is in check.sh bash file.